# TypeError: can't convert expression to float, with symbolic x, polynomial interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to run the following code but an error appears at the line with `S[i][0]`.

> TypeError: can't convert expression to float

I'm am sure that my variables `D[][]`, `h[]`, `age[]`, `A[]`, `B[]` and `n` are ok (they are floats). I think it has something to do with the symbolic figure `x`.

At the end, `S` is supposed to be a (7,1) vector of polynomes.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
age = np.arange(15,55,5)  
N = np.array([0, 7.442, 26.703, 41.635, 49.785, 50.209, 50.226])
n = len(N)

h = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n) :
    h[i] = age[i+1] - age[i]

mu = np.zeros(n)
lamda = np.zeros(n)
F = np.zeros((n,1))
A = np.zeros(n)
B = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(n) :
    mu[i] = h[i-1]/(h[i]+h[i-1])
    lamda[i] = h[i]/(h[i]+h[i-1])
    F[i][0] = (6*(N[i]*h[i-1] - h[i]*N[i-1]))/((h[i]+h[i-1])*h[i]*h[i-1])   

M = 2*np.eye(n,n) + 0.5*np.diag(np.ones((n-1)),1)+ 0.5*np.diag(np.ones((n-1)),1).T

D = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(M),F)

for i in range(n-1) :
    A[i] = (N[i+1] - N[i])/h[i] - (h[i]*(D[i+1][0] - D[i][0]))/6
    B[i] = N[i] - (((h[i])**2)*D[i][0])/6

def s(D, h, age, A, B, n) :
    S = np.zeros((n,1))
    x = sp.Symbol("x")
    for i in range(n) :
        S[i][0] = (D[i+1][0]*((x - age[i])**3))/(6*h[i]) - (D[i][0]*((x - age[i+1])**3))/(6*h[i]) + (A[i])*(x - age[i]) + B[i]
    return sp.simplify(S)


S = s(D, h, age, A, B, n)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. There's a space before ` def`, so the code does not run. Next, the last line has an unreferenced variable called `x`, so the code does not run. And: why not obey the Python rules of code formatting? If you use a good editor (an IDE like PyCharm), that's one click for you, but one click for everyone who tries to run your code. Also, it seems that the commented code at the end is not relevant. Remove it.

Comment: The problem is that `x` is involved in that long calculation and the result is symbolic, while numpy wants something numeric. You say you want `S` to be a vector. Do you actually intend to do vector calculations with it, or do you want a generic "array-like" container, like a list? If you tell me that, I can show you an appropriate solution.

Comment: By the way, for future reference, when someone asks you to provide a *minimal* example, you don't have to show your actual code. A simple `age = np.random.randn(8)` suffices. The same for the other variables. We don't care about the calculations being correct, we just want something concrete to copy-paste so we can reproduce the error and investigate it.

Comment: Thank you, Yes a list is okay, I just want to draw the function at the end. Each line of S would be drawn on a different interval.  Like S[0][0] drawn on the interval of x = [15,20] etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that while most of your variables are floats, `x` is symbolic, which causes all of those calculations in the end to be a symbolic object. Such objects are handled at python-level with classes, while numpy requires numbers, so it tries to apply `float()` to it. For example,

```
>> float(sp.Add(1, 1))
2.0

>> float(s.Add(1 + x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    float(sp.Add(1, x))
  File "C:\Users\ip507\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 239, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Since you don't intend to use an calcuations with the "array-like" `S` object, it can just be a list, where you collect the expressions.

```
def s(D, h, age, A, B, n):
    x = sp.Symbol("x")
    S = []
    for i in range(n):
        S.append((D[i+1][0]*((x - age[i])**3))/(6*h[i]) - (D[i][0]*((x - age[i+1])**3))/(6*h[i]) + (A[i])*(x - age[i]) + B[i])
    return S
```

Having said that, you have an error which causes an `IndexError`. `D` has a shape of (7, 1), but you call `D[i+1]`. It's something you'll need to address since I don't know your intentions.

Comment: Great, thank you. Yes I just added that D[n+1] = 0. I had some dimension issues.